# Custom style in PrimeNG component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

How to add some custom style in this html code:

```
 <p-tieredMenu #menu [model]="items" [popup]="true"></p-tieredMenu>
```

I would to change a `.ui-menu{}` and something else. How implement this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I create a file called prime.css in my assets folder. With the follow code:

```
.ui-menu{

}
```

And then import in my /src/styles.sass.

```
@import './assets/styles/prime.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement style like this attribute -> `[style]="{'width':'auto'}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an scss file and include it in your component and give a view encapsulation:none in component decorator.